# Passing PHP variable embedded in SVG to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, svg, web

I am writing a web application which pulls data from a MYSQL database using php. No problem with that side. The selected data is used to create ultimately an SVG image showing sports exercises for coaching. Works well so far.
Now I want to be able to use an SVG "onMouseOver" mouse call from the  embedded svg code to a Javascript function to display textual information regarding the coaching points for the exercise. The svg code is embedded in a php sprintf function.

```
$ID="E".$yourArray[$y-1]['ExerciseID'];
echo "Exercise ID is....". $ID."<br>";

$tablesvg=$tablesvg .sprintf('<use xlink:href="#table" id="%3$s" onMouseOver="showID()" fill="beige" x="%1$d" y="%2$d"/>',$tb1xcoord, $tbycoordoffset,$ID);
```

Problem is that no data from the php variable displays within the javascript function shown below. Function is  stable as the Alert text displays.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

  function showID()
  {
    var jsvar = '<?php echo $ID;?>';
    var test=document.getElementById(jsvar).getAttributeNS(null,"fill");
    alert("Exercise ID is:" + test);
  }
</script>
```

As long as I don't try to pass the PHP variable it does work - the DOM part in the JS function works if I hard code the value (E1).

Comment: Is the code that outputs the Javascript in a PHP function? Does the function have `global $ID;`?

Comment: Is the code that sets `$ID` looping through an array? Your use of `$yourArray[$y-1]` seems to suggest it. Which value do you expect `$ID` to hold in the Javascript?

Comment: Originally yes, but when it did not work I isolated the function in a Javascript area.

Comment: $ID set in a for loop through the array, would like to pass array value but thought it might be  simpler to assign that value to a  simple variable in php - when it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Pass the element as an argument to the function, rather than using the ID from the variable and then calling `getElementById`

```
$ID="E".$yourArray[$y-1]['ExerciseID'];
echo "Exercise ID is....". $ID."<br>";

$tablesvg=$tablesvg .sprintf('<use xlink:href="#table" id="%3$s" onMouseOver="showID(this)" fill="beige" x="%1$d" y="%2$d"/>',$tb1xcoord, $tbycoordoffset,$ID);
```

Then change the JS to:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

  function showID(elt)
  {
    var test=elt.id;
    alert("Exercise ID is:" + test);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Wicked - worked. Many thanks, hopefully I can now move ahead. The use of some form of hover to show the  text would  simplify the application rather than an alert as current. hard part is mixing all the technologies